# iText 7 (Java) When Large Table extend to next page it does not draw bottom border

Tags: java, itext7

In my report generation java application with iText 7, I need to get data from a large data tables which may extend to several pages.

My code segments to generate the table.

```java
    Table table = new Table(new float[] {0.4f, 1f, 1f, 1f, 1.3f, 1f, 1.3f, 0.6f,0.6f,1.2f}, true)
                .setWidth(UnitValue.createPercentValue(100))
                .setMarginTop(tblTopMargin)
                .setMarginBottom(0);
    int count = 0;
    while (!dataList.empty()) {
        String[] dataRow = dataList.poll();
        createDataRow(dataRow, table);
        count++;
        if(count % 10 == 0) {
            table.flush();
        }
    }
```

implementation of `createDataRaw` method is mentioned below,

```java
private void createDataRow(String[] a, Table table) {
    for (String s : a) {

      Paragraph content = new Paragraph(s)
        .setFontSize(7)
        .setFixedLeading(9)
        .setFontColor(new DeviceCmyk(0, 0, 0, 100));

      Cell cell = new Cell()
        .setBorder(new SolidBorder(ColorConstants.BLACK, 0.5f))
        .setPaddingLeft(2)
        .setPaddingTop(0)
        .setPaddingBottom(0)
        .setHorizontalAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.LEFT)
        .setVerticalAlignment(VerticalAlignment.MIDDLE)
        .add(content);

      table.addCell(cell);
    }
  }
```

with the given code table generated with all the data. But when there is a page break between tables then the bottom line of the table is not showing except for the last table bottom.

screenshots are attached here to get a more clear idea.

[image]

Can someone help me to solve this issue?

Comment: What you're seeing is a feature to let the reader of the document know at a glance that the table extends to the next page.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc is there any option to disable that feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code produces the desired result for me for the latest `7.1.16` version of iText:

```
    Table table = new Table(new float[] {0.4f, 1f, 1f}, true)
            .setWidth(UnitValue.createPercentValue(100))
            .setMarginBottom(0);
    document.add(table);
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 300; i++) {
        String[] dataRow = new String[] {"1\n2\n3\n4\n5\n6\n7\n8\n9\n10", "2\n3\nsf\n43", "3\nr\nsdfsd\n43"};
        createDataRow(dataRow, table);
        count++;
        if (count % 10 == 0) {
            table.flush();
        }
    }
    table.complete();

    document.close();
```

```
    private void createDataRow(String[] a, Table table) {
        for (String s : a) {
            Paragraph content = new Paragraph(s)
                    .setFontSize(7)
                    .setFixedLeading(9)
                    .setFontColor(new DeviceCmyk(0, 0, 0, 100));

            Cell cell = new Cell()
                    .setBorder(new SolidBorder(ColorConstants.BLACK, 0.5f))
                    .setPaddingLeft(2)
                    .setPaddingTop(0)
                    .setPaddingBottom(0)
                    .setHorizontalAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.LEFT)
                    .setVerticalAlignment(VerticalAlignment.MIDDLE)
                    .add(content);

            table.addCell(cell);
        }
    }
```

Visual result (end of first page):

[image: result]

Comment: What is the difference here? I did not see any difference.

Comment: Difference in code? You can use an online tool to check the difference or go line by line. Does this work on your end?

Comment: @AlexeySubach you must be fun at parties...
I did use a diff tool: https://www.diffchecker.com/hJI60DT2
And basically is just using different data, this is not the answer to OP question.
I'm facing a similar issue but in my case is the top border on the next page that is not drawn.